# Div not loading class

Tags: html, css

Hi what I am trying to do is have a container class like bootstrap but I am not wanting to use bootstrap due to memory limitations

css code:

```
.container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 950px;
}
```

html code:

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Testing</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Bootstrap isn't *that* big...especially if you customise it to only use the biits you want.

Comment: So when I use the class container in my div it wont use the class

Comment: What is it that's not working?

Comment: To add to @Paulie_D's comment, I download the LESS source version of Bootstrap and strip out anything that I'm not using, even column classes like `col-xs-*` or `col-lg-*`. By strip out I mean comment out so it's there if I need it later.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/j06hw5ro/

Comment: Just the grid stytem is about 50kb...that's less than most images.

Comment: Are you sure you're including your CSS file properly?

Comment: try replacing the link tag in your head  with <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Comment: Try adding the styles inline in the <head> as <style> </style>. If that works and your css file doesn't, you probably didn't link them correctly (check your console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your CSS stylesheet I deduce you want to see a centered div. There is no reason why that code should not working, except if the path to the stylesheet is not correct (check your console) or if your browser cannot infer the relationship between the linked resource and your html document, so add `rel=stylesheet` to your link tag.

If that does not work try adding a background color and lower the width of your container class, and see if it is working properly.

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/j06hw5ro/

Answer (score 0):

**CSS CODE:**

`body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
       display: block;
       margin: auto;
       width: 950px;
       background-color: #FEFAE2;
    }`

**HTML CODE:**

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="container">
           <h1>Testing</h1>
        </div>
     </body>
    </html>`